# How to set tasks by variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have been working with Ansible for a long time, and it came to mind that I would love to add customization into my playbooks from user input.  But the following plays throw errors:

```
---
# Test user input in play
- hosts: 10.10.10.10
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

# User input can be received via vars_prompt;
  vars_prompt:
  - name:    "q1"
    prompt:  "answer to q1?"
    private: no
    default: 0

  tasks:
  - name:
    block:
      - name: "If user input is 1, then create /tmp/success"
        shell: touch /tmp/success
    when: {{ q1 }} == "1"
```

## 1 This is throwing an error at the bold below:

*ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key ( on line: when: "{{ q1 }}" **is** 1 )*

## 2 The message also Specifies;

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
```

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

I've changed the quotation marks to single/double/nil on both values, and this still occurs, I am stumped.

What I am looking to do is to provide the user with a list of input they can provide with **vars_prompt**, and then complete specific tasks using that input as a requisite with **when:**.

Comment: Please include the actual playbook. It appears that you typed it in manually instead of copying and pasting it.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed the tasks heading.  Thank-you.

I've modified my initial post.

Comment: And that is the playbook as I've created it (which I have validated by copy/pasting that code block into a yml file on my ansible server).  I want to make certain I understand the syntax and application of the playbook before I utilize tasks with it.

Comment: OK, then what is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the when condition into the braces. [Ansible conditions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) are expanded by default.

Try

> when: q1 == "1"